# Unable to render flatlist items in a row

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using flat list to render some data from faker js, everything works when I am using default flexDirection: "column" rendering type, however I want to render the items in row and this code does not work.

```
    <FlatList
      style={{
        flexDirection: "row",
        flexWrap: "wrap"
      }}
      data={fakePeople}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.fullName}
    />
```

Nothing is being rendered, but as soon as I take the `flexDirection: "row",` everything works fine.

Here is a link for the demo

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-galois-5zpnp1?file=/src/App.js:718-916

Is this a bug or does React native flatlist does not support row layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `horizontal` prop like this,

```
<FlatList
  horizontal
  data={fakePeople}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.fullName}
/>
```

Or if you want several items per column

```
<FlatList
  numColumns={3}
  data={fakePeople}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.fullName}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `horizontal` FlatList prop as [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#horizontal) says , and if you want to make some like grid layout you can use `numColumns` prop https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#numcolumns

I edited a few your [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-heisenberg-lo8rt8?file=/src/App.js)